# Translate the camera along it's forward axis after rotation in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, coordinate-systems, glm-math

I want to rotate the camera 30° `view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(-30.0f), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));` and then move it forward along the new forward axis `view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));`. Is this hard to achieve without having to use glm::lookAt function?

Comment: Have you tried putting those lines one after the other? If that doesn't work, try applying the transformations in reverse order.

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) especially the last sublinks ... you can extract the forward direction directly from camera matrix ...  but beware cumulated ModelView matrix is not a camera matrix and also camera matrix is usually inverse ...